# Intellij shows Project Language Level as 12 maximum despite having java version 17 SDK

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

[image: language level shows 12 max, nothing beyond that]

As you can see in the image above, the SDK is set to 17 and yet i am not seeing language level up to 17 or higher. What am i missing?

Even Java compiler shows up to 12 bytecode version.

[image: java compiler also showing only up to 12]

Comment: What version of IDEA are you using?

Comment: What have you configured in your pom file? Please show the full pom file?

Comment: @emptyjar 2019.1

Comment: Upgrade.  That is your problem.

Comment: That version doesn't support Java 17. According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html, support for Java 17 wasn't added until 2021.2.  Though as of this comment, the latest version is 2023.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to add an answer so this can hopefully be helpful to others.

The language level version available is dependent on the version of Jetbrains IDEA itself.  As @Slaw pointed out, there is a table provided by Jetbrains

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html

By that table, 2019.1 will support up to language level 13.  At least 2021.2 is required for language level 17.

Comment: Tip to readers: After deleting all manually installed copies of IntelliJ, install [*JetBrains Toolbox App*](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/). Let that app automatically install IntelliJ, and then let that app **automatically update IntelliJ**.  With that app you can even enroll in automatically getting early-access versions, if you so desire.